# Anything like a SQL Server proxy that will cache data accessed locally?

Tags: sql-server, caching, local

Wild shot this, but does anyone know of a kind of proxy that will cache the data used in a SQL Server query locally - so the same query can be run again offline?

What I'm doing here is developing stored procedures against a (very large) database of several dozen tables.  I'd like to be able to have the data that was used in the returning of the result set cached locally, so that when I'm not connected to the network, I can continue refining the stored proc business logic and have it return data off the local cached copy of tables I have.  I only want a portion of each table locally.

I could SSIS a chunk of each of the tables to similarly named copies locally, but to find all the related data is a chunk of work in itself.  I was wondering if there's anything out there that does something similar.

(I want to cache the data locally in the same table structure as the networked SQL Server, so I can continue tweaking the SQL against it).

disclaimer : googled "SQL Server cache query data locally" and variations...

Only "MTCache" turned up, but I can't find out anything beyond the research paper?

Thanks,
Ray

Comment: I know this doesn't solve the whole issue, but what about staying connected to your session, and utilizing temp tables if you need to keep hitting the data during development? This would mean you wouldn't keep having to hit the tables, and you could index those tables as well to help speed things up.

Comment: I wonder if something like ScaleARC would help?  Not cheap or free...would require a hardware fix.